# Why is my Flot plot function not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I'm trying to follow [this](http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/basic-usage/index.html) tutorial to make a simple graph. However, I'm getting an empty divider when I load the page.

Relevant code:

```
<head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/flot/jquery.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/flot/jquery.flot.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $.plot($("#graphs"), [[[0,0],[1,1]]);
});
</script>

</head>

<body>
<div id="graphs" style="width:600px; height:400px">
</div> 
</body>
```

I have page.php in the www directory, then the two .js files in www/js/flot

Comment: What does it mean not working? And what is empty divider? Upload the code to http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: The divider, with id graphs, is empty when I load the page. It should contain the graph.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ym6dbt10/

Answer (score 1):

You have an unnecessary bracket in your code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.plot($("#graph"), [[0,0],[1,1]]);
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/ym6dbt10/3/

You should use your browser console to debug that kind of problems, if you don't understand the error it gives, write it down here to maybe people can help, if you just write it doesn't work, it gives no information.